# Multiply Export pathes for a workspace package

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, commonjs, webpack-5

I've added a "common" package to our yarn (version 1) workspaces,
This package is storing a services files in TypeScript.

Other packages uses this package as follow (which works):

`import {services} from 'common'`

To transcript the files from TS to JS I've setup a Webpack (version 5) configuration with the following:

```
    module.exports = {
      entry: {
        main: './src/index.ts',
        service1: './src/services/service1.ts',
        service2: './src/services/service2.ts',
      },
      devtool: 'inline-source-map',
      module: {
        rules: [{
          test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
          exclude: /(node_module|lib)/,
          use: [{
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                cacheDirectory: true,
              },
            },
            {
              loader: 'ts-loader',

            },
            {
              loader: '@stavalfi/babel-plugin-module-resolver-loader',
              options: {
                // all those options will go directly to babel-plugin-module-resolver plugin.
                // Read babel-plugin-module-resolver DOCS to see all options:
                // https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver/blob/master/DOCS.md
                root: ['./src'],
                extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.d.ts', '.ts', '.tsx'],
              },
            },
          ],
        }, ],
      },
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
      },
      output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: resolve(__dirname, 'lib'),
      },
      mode: 'production'
    }
```

I'm trying to export our services so it can be used as follow:

`import service1 from 'common/services/service1'`

I've tried editing the `package.json` with `exports` entry:

```
{
  "name": "common",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "main": "lib/main.js",
  "typings": "lib/index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    ".": "./lib/main.js",
    "./services/service1": "./lib/services/service1.js"
  },
  "files": [
    "lib"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  }
...
```

tsconfig.json file:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonJS",
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
  }
```

Although all this, I keep receiving the following errors:
`Cannot find module 'common/services/service1' or its corresponding type declarations.`

The files are present correctly in the lib files, but I'm not sure how else to handle this issue..

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: just change import service1 from 'common/services/service1' to import service1 from 'common/lib/services/service1'